# Deny access to IIS Server from IP local range

Tags: web-application, webserver, server, iis, windows-server

I have a local IIS 10 Server, this server runs a critical application.

I want to deny access for this server from IP local network and allow only 2 or 3 IP-addresses. Additionally I want to log any attempt to access this server.

How do I can do this ? It is a way to add a .conf file like apache for example? Or use a firewall?

Answer (score 2):

In IIS Manager, (if the sub-feature has been installed) there is a node for `IP Address and Domain Restrictions` which will allow you to determine which IP addresses you want to allow and/or deny either for a specific website or for all websites on the server.

If you don't see this node, it is because the sub-feature has not been installed.  In that case, from the Server Manager Dashboard window choose `Add Roles and Features` and navigate to the `Server Roles` node, and then to the `Web Server` role.  Under the `Web Server` role node there is a `Security` sub-node, and from there, check the box for the `IP and Domain Restrictions` item and save.  You should now be able to create IP allow and deny rules in IIS Manager for your website or the server.